# シェルスクリプトで配列に空のデータを代入させない方法

Tags: bash, shellscript, array

シェルスクリプトで次のように配列paramにデータを代入するとき、$valが空だった場合、そのまま配列にも空のデータが作られてしまいます。「"」をつけなければ空のデータが代入されることはないのですが、その場合、$valにスペースが含まれていると複数のデータに分かれてしまいます。
param+=("$val")
配列に空のデータを代入させたくない場合、代入前に$valのデータをチェックするしか方法はないのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `param+=(${val:+"$val"})` ではどうでしょうか。`:+` については `man bash` の `Parameter Expansion` の項を参照して下さい。

Comment: `:+`の後に変数を指定できるとは気づきませんでした。`param+=(${val:+"$val"})`で問題ありません。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @metropolis 解決にしたいので、回答に書いていただけないでしょうか。ついでにもう一件の方も回答の方にご記入お願いいたします。

Comment: ご自身で回答して、それを(ご自身で)承認することが可能です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
param+=(${val:+"$val"})
```

`:+`については`man bash`の`Parameter Expansion`の項を参照。